# Getting 500 POST (Server Internal Error) - {"errorMessage":"Error: data and hash arguments required"} when sending sign-in form data to the server

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt, mern, http-status-code-500

I'm working on my first ecommerce project with the MERN stack and I'm stuck with this error when I click on the submit button to send the login data to the server.
It's a problem of bcrypt.compare, but I can't solve it as I seem to have provided the required parameters (password from the client side and password from mongoDB).
I also checked the database and the registered user data is correct, including the hashpasswords.

This is my backend code from signin controller:

```
import express from 'express'; 
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import validator from 'validator';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {User} from '../models/User.js';


dotenv.config();
const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const JWT_EXPIRE = process.env.JWT_EXPIRE;

export const signIn = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({email});

        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({errorMessage : 'Invalid credentials'})
        }

        if(!email || !password){
            return  res.status(400).json({errorMessage: 'All fields are required'})
         }
        
        if(!validator.isEmail(email)){
            return res.status(400).json({errorMessage : 'Invalid email'})
        }

           
        //JWT
        const payload = {
            user : {
                _id : user._id
            }
        }

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if(!isMatch){
            return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: 'Invalid credentials'})
        }
        else{
            jwt.sign(
                payload, 
                JWT_SECRET,
                {expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRE},
                (err, token) => {
                    if(err) console.log ('Jwt error: ', err);
    
                    const {_id, username, email, role} = user;
    
                    res.json({
                        token,
                        user : {_id, username, email, role}
                    })
                }
            )
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
       return  res.status(500).json({errorMessage : `${error}`})
    }
}
```

This is the frontend code portion:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import validator from 'validator';
import SignInUI from './SignInUI';
import { signin } from '../../api/auth';

onst SignIn = () => {
    const[signinData, setSigninData] = useState({
        email : '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        loading: false,
        redirectToProfile: false,
    })

    const{email, password, errorMessage, loading, redirectToProfile} = signinData;

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSigninData({
            ...signinData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            errorMessage: '',
        })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //API POST LOGIC

        if(!email || !password){
            setSigninData({
                ...signinData,
                errorMessage : 'All fields are required'
            })
        }
        else if(!validator.isEmail(email)){
            setSigninData({
                ...signinData,
                errorMessage : 'Invalid email'
            })
        }
        else{
            const data = {email, password};

            setSigninData({
                ...signinData,
                loading: true
            })

            signin(data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                setSigninData({
                    ...signinData,
                    loading: false
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                if(error.response.status === 400){
                    setSigninData({
                        ...signinData,
                        errorMessage: 'Invalid credentials',
                        loading: false
                    })
                }
                else{
                    setSigninData({
                        ...signinData,
                        errorMessage: error.toString(),
                        loading: false
                    })
                }

            })
        }

      
    }

 
    return (

        <SignInUI
            signinData = {signinData}
            handleChange = {handleChange}
            handleSubmit = {handleSubmit}
        />
        
    )
}

export default SignIn
```

Thank you very much and sorry for errors or confusion: I am a beginner web developer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way? This is just an example of how you can achieve your goal:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Validation failure!",
            errors: errors.errors
        })
    } else {
        const result = await userService.findByEmail(email);
        if (result.length == 0 || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password))) {
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Email or password is incorrect.",
            })
        } else {
            jwt.sign({user: result[0]}, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {expiresIn: '1d'}, (err, token) => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    message: "Logged in successfully.",
                    token: token
                })
            });
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Source code: [GitHub link](https://github.com/rashedrahat/memes-api/blob/main/api/user/user.controller.js)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, but I finally solved the problem. Inside the User model file, in the "password" field, I had set "select" to false.